# How to install/update gcc-4.6 on openSUSE 11.2 (x86_64)?

Tags: linux, gcc, opensuse, libstdc++

I met an err when I installed JikesRVM, that is,

```
skipping incompatible /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.4/libstdc++.so when searching for -lstdc++
```

So I am trying to install/update it to a later version. Now, the machine already has

```
gcc (SUSE Linux) 4.4.1 [gcc-4_4-branch revision 150839]
```

I am new to openSUSE, could you help?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Dmitri, I only know that I have /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.4/libstdc++.so

Comment: after 'zypper search libstdc++', I got these: 'i | libstdc++44             
i | libstdc++44-32bit 
i | libstdc++44-devel
  | libstdc++44-devel-32bit '

Comment: So it may be not caused by "incompatible"? Actually, on another machine with openSUSE 12.1 (x86_64) and gcc 4.6, there is no such error.

Comment: I was wrong as for the possible fix. 32bit support for the compiler in SUSE requires a separate package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install 32 bit support for the GNU C/C++ compiler since JikesRVM on x86_64 currently supports only the 32 bit architecture.

To install this support in OpenSuSE 11.2 type

```
    sudo zypper install gcc44-32bit gcc-32bit libstdc++44-devel-32bit
```

The first two provide runtime support for the C language and the 32-bit version of libgcc, the GCC low level runtime library. The third provides the 32-bit version of libstdc++, both the static import library and the dynamic library. It is the static libstdc++.a that was missing for JikesRVM.

To verify that the 32bit C++ build system is installed correctly you can test it with the following

```
    echo "int main(){}" | g++ -x c++ -m32 -
```

**Note** Official support for OpenSuSE 11.2 has ended. Evergreen support will be available through 2013. Yet it is reasonable to update to 11.3 or a  later version soon.

Comment: after it, I got these "Reading installed packages...
'gcc44-32bit' is already installed.
No update candidate for 'gcc44-32bit'.
'gcc-c++-32bit' not found.
'gcc-32bit' is already installed.
No update candidate for 'gcc-32bit'.
Resolving package dependencies...

Nothing to do.
"

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. Could you explain a little more?

Comment: Amazing! the last library (libstdc++44-devel-32bit) was installed, and the building of JikesRVM past! Is the reason that last library? Why this is important, as I already have the other 3 similar libraries?